# i have problem in my code javascript function onchange()

Tags: javascript, html

What is wrong with this script ?

```js
function swapImage() {
  debugger

  var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
  var dropd = document.getElementById("swapImg");
  image.src = dropd.options[dropd.selectedIndex].value;


  var model = document.getElementById("model");
  var heading = document.getElementById("heading3");
  var textGrey = document.getElementById("textGrey");
  var textGrey2 = document.getElementById("textGrey2");

  if (dropd.value == "http://placehold.it/150x150") {
    model.innerHTML = "A4";
    heading.innerHTML = "This text matches A4 model";
    textGrey.innerHTML = "kjhkjh we ewf kjikjkj we";
    textGrey2.innerHTML = "hf efjkj efe  edeeeeejm dff";
    return false;
  } else if (dropd.value == "http://placehold.it/350x150") {
    model.innerHTML = "A6";
    heading.innerHTML = "This text matches A6 model";
    textGrey.innerHTML = "xxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxx";
    textGrey2.innerHTML = "yy yyyy yyyy yy";
    return false;
  } else if (dropd.value == "http://placehold.it/350x250") {
    model.innerHTML = "A8";
    heading.innerHTML = "This text matches the A8 model";
    textGrey.innerHTML = "zzzz zzzzz";
    textGrey2.innerHTML = "pppp ppp pp p p";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="swapImg" name="model" class="modelSelect" onchange="swapImage()">
  <option value="http://placehold.it/150x150">A4</option>
  <option value="http://placehold.it/350x150" selected="selected">A6</option>
  <option value="http://placehold.it/350x250">A8</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<div id="carbox">
  <h2 id="model" class="model">A6</h2>
  <img id="imageToSwap" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="544" height="203" style="margin-left:275px; margin-top:-82px" />

  <div id="carbox-bottom">
    <h3 id="heading3" class="heading3">Loren ipsum dolor sit ame</h3>
    <p id="textGrey" class="textGrey">Coisteahi fwior he qvbsi </p>
    <p id="textGrey2" class="textGrey2">Coisteahi fwior he qvbsi dolo</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6xsro2cj/

Comment: Actually, can you tell us what is wrong with the script? What isn't working?

Comment: When i choose option the image change as well the text

Comment: I put your code into a stack snippet in your question and it appears to work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your code. But in jsfiddle, to make it work globally, you should use specify load type = No wrap, otherwise the script will be loaded in onLoad or DOM ready which make it is not available for your onchange call.
Just updated your fiddle with "No wrap" option on the JS window section.

**Updated:**

Full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



  <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
      img {
         width: 200px;
      }
  </style>



</head>
<body>
    <select id="swapImg" name="model" class="modelSelect" onchange="swapImage()">
   <option value="http://placehold.it/150x150">A4</option>
<option value="http://placehold.it/350x150" selected="selected">A6</option>
<option value="http://placehold.it/350x250">A8</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<div id="carbox">
  <h2 id="model" class="model">A6</h2>
  <img id="imageToSwap" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="544" height="203" style="margin-left:275px; margin-top:-82px" />

  <div id="carbox-bottom">
    <h3 id="heading3" class="heading3">Loren ipsum dolor sit ame</h3>
    <p id="textGrey" class="textGrey">Coisteahi fwior he qvbsi dolo wetiuyy thuoi loren ipsum dolar </p>
    <p id="textGrey2" class="textGrey2">Coisteahi fwior he qvbsi dolo</p>
  </div>
</div>


  <!-- TODO: JS script is be added here -->

  <script type="text/javascript">



function swapImage() {
  debugger
  var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
  var dropd = document.getElementById("swapImg");
  image.src = dropd.options[dropd.selectedIndex].value;


  var model = document.getElementById("model");
  var heading = document.getElementById("heading3");
  var textGrey = document.getElementById("textGrey");
  var textGrey2 = document.getElementById("textGrey2");

  if (dropd.value == "http://placehold.it/150x150") {
    model.innerHTML = "A4";
    heading.innerHTML = "This text matches A4 model";
    textGrey.innerHTML = "kjhkjh we ewf kjikjkj we";
    textGrey2.innerHTML = "hf efjkj efe  edeeeeejm dff";
    return false;
  } else if (dropd.value == "http://placehold.it/350x150") {
    model.innerHTML = "A6";
    heading.innerHTML = "This text matches A6 model";
    textGrey.innerHTML = "xxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxx";
    textGrey2.innerHTML = "yy yyyy yyyy yy";
    return false;
  } else if (dropd.value == "http://placehold.it/350x250") {
    model.innerHTML = "A8";
    heading.innerHTML = "This text matches the A8 model";
    textGrey.innerHTML = "zzzz zzzzz";
    textGrey2.innerHTML = "pppp ppp pp p p";
    return false;
  }
}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks,
but when i pute it in local file doesn't work

Comment: You must add your script to the html file either in head or at the bottom of body tag with <script>

Comment: Open your fiddle with this link: http://jsfiddle.net/6xsro2cj/show, then use Save as function in your browser to save html+js to your computer. Open that file, you will see how to organize the code html + js properly.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

If you want to make the onChange work in jsFiddle, you will have to make your script work globally. You will either have to change the load type of the Javascript part of the jsFiddle to wrap at the end of the head or body tag.

**Solution**

See the 'load type' selectbox in the picture below to achieve this in the future:

[image: load type changed]

Comment: Thanks, but when i pute it in local file doesn't work

Comment: Where do you put the code in the local file? Do you have an example of that script?

Comment: function swapImage(){   
debugger
var image=document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
var dropd=document.getElementById("swapImg");
image.src=dropd.options[dropd.selectedIndex].value;    
var model=document.getElementById("model");
var textGrey=document.getElementById("textGrey");
if(dropd.label == "localhost/images/car_slider_demo.png"){
   model.innerHTML="BMW";
   textGrey.innerHTML="kjhkjh we ewf kjikjkj we";
   return false;
}
else if (dropd.value== "localhost/images/amg.png"){
   model.innerHTML= "AMG";
   textGrey.innerHTML ="xxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxx";
   return false;
}
}

Answer (score 0):

To work this answer in your Local file and scripts tag at the end of it or change the option in jsfiddle as to `no wrap - bottom of body` me http://jsfiddle.net/6xsro2cj/10/

```
<select id="swapImg" name="model" class="modelSelect" onchange="swapImage()">
   <option value="http://placehold.it/150x150">A4</option>
<option value="http://placehold.it/350x150" selected="selected">A6</option>
<option value="http://placehold.it/350x250">A8</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<div id="carbox">
  <h2 id="model" class="model">A6</h2>
  <img id="imageToSwap" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="544" height="203" style="margin-left:275px; margin-top:-82px" />

  <div id="carbox-bottom">
    <h3 id="heading3" class="heading3">Loren ipsum dolor sit ame</h3>
    <p id="textGrey" class="textGrey">Coisteahi fwior he qvbsi dolo wetiuyy thuoi loren ipsum dolar </p>
    <p id="textGrey2" class="textGrey2">Coisteahi fwior he qvbsi dolo</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function swapImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
  var dropd = document.getElementById("swapImg");

  //-------this line is changed by me
  image.src = dropd.value;


  var model = document.getElementById("model");
  var heading = document.getElementById("heading3");
  var textGrey = document.getElementById("textGrey");
  var textGrey2 = document.getElementById("textGrey2");

  // a little bit improve comparison as dropd will be a node of html collections
  if (dropd.value == dropd[0].value) {
    model.innerHTML = "A4";
    heading.innerHTML = "This text matches A4 model";
    textGrey.innerHTML = "kjhkjh we ewf kjikjkj we";
    textGrey2.innerHTML = "hf efjkj efe  edeeeeejm dff";
    return false;
  } else if (dropd.value == dropd[1].value) {
    model.innerHTML = "A6";
    heading.innerHTML = "This text matches A6 model";
    textGrey.innerHTML = "xxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxx";
    textGrey2.innerHTML = "yy yyyy yyyy yy";
    return false;
  } else if (dropd.value == dropd[2].value) {
    model.innerHTML = "A8";
    heading.innerHTML = "This text matches the A8 model";
    textGrey.innerHTML = "zzzz zzzzz";
    textGrey2.innerHTML = "pppp ppp pp p p";
    return false;
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Are you going to explain your answer or are you going to make us treat it as a game of spot-the-differences?

Comment: @j08691 i have commented out the difference as show above